# Path of OTG in Android device

Tags: android, file, usb, usb-otg

I am developing an `Android` application in which I have to get details of `USB device` connected to Tablet via `OTG` .

when I use `sys/bus/usb0/devices` then I am getting list of all devices of Tablet while I want to only fetch device name attached via OTG port .

Is there ant way to get which device is in built and which device is connected to Tablet.

When I used  path `/storage/usb0/` and `/storage/usbdisk0`/ , then I didnt get any device whicle device is attached via `OTG` port.

Please can anyone tell me how can I get the `USB` details attached via `OTG` port to Tablet

Comment: on my moto g it's `/storage/usbdisk/`

Comment: `to get details of USB device`. Which details are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Below example link provides data like :

1)The Device class
2)The USB device path
3)The Vendor ID (VID) and the Product ID (PID).
4)A List of all interfaces and their endpoints. etc...

[see github example](https://github.com/alt236/USB-Device-Info---Android)