# Android Find path of already inserted USB Media

Tags: android, android-external-storage

My device has two paths which point to two USB ports on the device /storage/udisk/ and /storage/udisk2/ .  I would like to find these paths programmatically.  I can find via Broadcast Receiver when the devices are inserted but this does not work for devices which are already inserted at boot.  Is there a database of devices connected which can be accessed?

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns the path to the SDCard only and not inserted USB devices.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns the path to the SDCard`. No. You get a path to external memory. Not to a removable micro sd card.

Comment: see here for a solution (my answer was removed): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601157/path-of-otg-in-android-device/29413243

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path of OTG in Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601157/path-of-otg-in-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling with the same problem. It seems that different manufacturer have different path for USB.

Mostly the real path for a usb drive is under **/mnt/media_rw/** ( e.g. /mnt/media_rw/usbotg), and link path is under **/storage/** (for example /storage/usbotg). However, this doesn't happen always. I have tested in 3 different brands and find out the followings:

- Lenovo Tab2 A10-30 has /storage/usbotg as the link to the USB
  storage.
- Nexus 9 shows nothing for usb-relevant path.
- Samsung mobiles normally name the path /storage/UsbDiskA,
  /storage/UsbDiskB, ... /storage/UsbDiskF.

When you use ADB shell command "cat /proc/mounts", you can find that some difference can be made after you plug in the USB disk. In my Lenovo tablet, it adds these two new lines:

> /dev/block/vold/8:1 /mnt/media_rw/usbotg vfat
>   rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
>   0 0 /dev/fuse /storage/usbotg fuse
>   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other
>   0 0

Comment: Have you found a solution using any APIs? On a Nexus 6P, I get a /mnt/media_rw/XXXXX but nothing in /storage/. Hidden API GetVolumeList() doesn't report the USB device! And getExternalFilesDirs() continues to only list the internal storage as if there was no other device!

Comment: see my new answer - libaums

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Path of OTG in Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601157/path-of-otg-in-android-device/29413243#29413243)

The answer shows how to list USB OTG devices and their respective path. And it answers OP's question: "I would like to find these paths programmatically".

I've used the answer's github link to figure out how to find these paths programmatically.

FWIW, all information is gathered from /sys/bus/usb/devices/. The point to filter out non-OTG devices as it is performed in the github library.

Answer (score 0):

The open-source library **libaums** helps a lot when you are working with USB https://github.com/magnusja/libaums

Comment: I want to try this library but i cannot get it to work. Still new to java and how to implement the step properly using libaums. I can import the library using implement step but start with usbmasstorage, my app crash when start. I put it on onCreate() method. I still unable to find the workable way to work with libaums.

Comment: I have used it some years ago. So I don't know the compatibility with the current Android libraries. You can check your debug log to see what could be the reason for the crash.