# unable to write File to usb storage

Tags: android, storage, android-usb

I am trying to create file dir to connected usb storage I have written following code to create dir :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.example.usbtest.USB_PERMISSION";
    UsbManager mUsbManager;
    UsbDevice device;

    String s = null;
    TextView tvusb;

    private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if (device != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "permission allowed" + device, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //call method to set up device communication
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "permission not allowed" + device, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("usb", "permission denied for device " + device);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tvusb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvusb);

        mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
            device = deviceIterator.next();

            s = device.getDeviceName();

            int pid = device.getProductId();
            int vid = device.getVendorId();
            device = deviceList.get(s);

            tvusb.setText(s + "\n" + Integer.toString(pid) + "\n" + Integer.toString(vid));
        }


        PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;


        mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);


        registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

        mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);


        File fileContact = new File(s, "Contact");
        if (!fileContact.exists()) {
            fileContact.mkdirs();
        }

        if (!confirmDir(fileContact)) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to create " + String.valueOf(fileContact), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

    private static boolean confirmDir(File dir) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) return true;  // already exists
        if (dir.exists()) return false;      // already exists, but is not a directory
        return dir.mkdirs();                 // create it
    }

}
```

manifest:

```
<manifest

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.usb"></uses-permission>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory"/>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter"/>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have also written - `File fileContact = new File("/storage/emulated/0", "Contact");`

But I am unable to create dir to usb storage.

How can I create dir to usb storage?

Comment: Can you add your manifest file?

Comment: i have attached manifest.

Comment: @LaurIvan please checked my manifest file. i think it has the all the required permission for create file on usb storage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android write files to USB via OTG cable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760025/android-write-files-to-usb-via-otg-cable)

Comment: @LaurIvan i have implement [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34048175/3997016) but there is no option showing for secondary storage  or usb storage

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601157/path-of-otg-in-android-device) the path varies from device to device.

Comment: but this is also not showing secondary storage( memory card)

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: i am testing on 4.4 .

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your problem is that you want to write a file on the external storage. In this case, you should only need the `*EXTERNAL*` permissions. According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage) you'll need to:

- check if the media is available and writable with something like:

  ```
  /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
  public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
      String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
      if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
  ```

  (code verbatim from the source)
- Then, you need to use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` or `getExternalFilesDir()` depending on your files' policy (public or private to app).

For accessing the removable media, you should use the *Storage Access Framework* as outlined in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28760025/515948) with the `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: i have connected pendrive through otg cable . so i want to create file on that pendrive. With this i am only access my internal memory storage not pendrive.